Выбор опций для виртуального окружения в PyCharm
При создании проекта в PyCharm у тебя спросят какой тип интерпритатора выбрать: Project venv, Base conda, Custom environment. Так вот я обычно выбирал Project venv и даже не задумывался почему и есть ли в них разница. В чем разница данных опций?


как задать хороший вопрос

Все достаточно просто.
Начнем с того, что хорошей практикой считается иметь свое виртуальное окружение для каждого проекта. Виртуальное окружение обеспечивает поддеркжу разных версий для python, а так же набор и версии тех модулей, которые необходимы для конекретного проекта.
PyCharm из коробки дает возможность не заморачиваться и автоматически равзвертывает виртуальное окружение под проект, это Project venv. Документация лежит здесь
Conda предназначена также для развертывания и управления виртуальным окружением. Мой выбор не использовать конду без необходимости (это субъективно и не стоит ориентироваться на мой выбор). Документация лежит здесь
Если же у вас по каким то причинам, уже есть виртуальное окружение, которое походит под данный проект, то вы можете просто указать путь до него, это Custom enviroment.
Выбор из предоставленных опций - это всегда гибкость и удобство, которое дает ide. Если вас устраивал Project venv, то продолжайет его использовать и переходите к следущим опциям по мере необходимости.
Из документации можно забрать еще пару моментов для более полного покружения

Для версий python 3.3 и выше используется модуль venv, а не модули третьих сторон
PyCharm может создавать виртуальное окружение, основанное на файле зависимостей requirements.txt

PS
Что такое модуль venv и какие еще бывают можно прочитать в этом ответе на ruSo
Вопрос: "Что лучше?" не стоит и не корректен. Это либо вкус разработчика, либо условия, которые могут появляться из-за разных ограничений или установленных рутин разработки командой.

Вот модуль virtualenv со скриншота в вопросе как раз сторонний, существовал до Python 3.3 (начальная 0.8 версия вышла в 2007 году), и все еще поддерживается. Говорят, работает быстрее чем стандартный venv. Но минус как раз в том, что его нужно устанавливать отдельно.

@insolor так на Ubuntu и Debian даже venv ставить надо в нынешних реалиях, он отдельным модулем идет, python3-venv. Вообще дело вкуса, хоть virtualenv и популярен, и быстрее, и функций больше, я никогда его не использовал. Надо будет попробовать как нибудь на досуге
